# delphi $IfNDEF command

Tags: delphi

I am sorry i know this is a really noobish question but can someone see this code and explain what this code is supposed to do, and delphi 7 keeps giving me error on the line begin stating expecting : or ,

```
{$IFDEF CRYPT_BLOCK}
  nested blocks not allowed!
{$ENDIF}
{$DEFINE CRYPT_BLOCK}
{$IFOPT O+}
  {$DEFINE SAVE_OPT}
{$ENDIF}
{$O-}
{$IfNDef UNSAFE_CRYPT}
begin
{$ENDIF}
asm db   $EB, $06, $EB, $FC, $EB, $FC, $FF, $F8 end;
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to show more code. That code is out of context. What appears before it?

Comment: That code is scary. The `asm db` at the end emits whatever you see there straight into the code; And what it emits starts with an unconditional relative short jump, nothing after the first two bytes matters. Looks like obfuscation to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Step-by-step;

```
{$IFDEF CRYPT_BLOCK}
  nested blocks not allowed!
{$ENDIF}
```

I assume this code is somehow `{$INCLUDE}`-ed. This code doesn't want to be included twice, so it will (later) define the precompiler symbol `CRYPT_BLOCK`; The code above tests if the symbol is defined `{$IFDEF CRYPT_BLOCK}` and if it is then it does something that's not going to compile (`nested blocks not allowed!`). When the programmer sees that she's going to know she `{$INCLUDE}` -ed this stuff twice.

```
{$DEFINE CRYPT_BLOCK}
```

This defines the symbol that's tested with the block above. If the compiler got here without complaints then the symbol hasn't already been defined.

```
{$IFOPT O+}
  {$DEFINE SAVE_OPT}
{$ENDIF}
```

Checks whether compiler optimization is enabled. If it is then the symbol `SAVE_OPT` is defined, so that the compiler option can be restored. When we see this we assume the code is going to change the `{$O}` compiler option.

```
{$O-}
```

Sure enough, optimization is now disabled.

```
{$IfNDef UNSAFE_CRYPT}
begin
{$ENDIF}
```

If the symbol `UNSAFE_CRYPT` is not defined then let the compiler see a `begin` keyword.

```
asm db   $EB, $06, $EB, $FC, $EB, $FC, $FF, $F8 end;
```

This is just a bit of scary assembler code; Someone's idea of "obfuscating" code; Not a very good idea. The first two bytes (`$EB`, `$06`) is a relative jump to exactly after all this code. In other words, you could include this series of assembly almost anywhere, the CPU will simply jump over it. Then follows a weird series of jumps, the second `$Eb` `$FC` is actually a jump to where the first jump would be, and so one. The final two bytes (`$FF`, `$F8`) don't actually make any sense (they're not valid Intel x86 instructions) so I assume that's ome kind of payload.

Comment: Thanks for explaining in such details